# This XmlWriter does not support base64 encoded data

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a class like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [NonSerialized] public byte[] Bytes;
}
```

When a `List<Data>` hits the serialization method below, it occasionally dies with

> InvalidOperationException "This
>   XmlWriter does not support base64
>   encoded data."

As you can see, I am not directly encoding anything, just using the default serialization mechanism.

```
private static XDocument Serialize<T>( T source )
{
    var target = new XDocument( );
    var s = new XmlSerializer( typeof( T ) );
    using( XmlWriter writer = target.CreateWriter( ) )
    {
        s.Serialize( writer, source );
    }
    return target;
}
```

The data will have `Name` properties that are English words separated by underscores. The `Value` property will by similar except with added math operators or numbers (they are mathematical expressions).

Does anyone know what is causing it and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[XmlIgnore]` instead of `[NonSerialized]`. The latter is for the SOAP and binary formatters, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx):

> When using the BinaryFormatter or
>   SoapFormatter classes to serialize an
>   object, use the NonSerializedAttribute
>   attribute to prevent a field from
>   being serialized. For example, you can
>   use this attribute to prevent the
>   serialization of sensitive data.
>
> The target objects for the
>   NonSerializedAttribute attribute are
>   public and private fields of a
>   serializable class. By default,
>   classes are not serializable unless
>   they are marked with
>   SerializableAttribute. During the
>   serialization process all the public
>   and private fields of a class are
>   serialized by default. Fields marked
>   with NonSerializedAttribute are
>   excluded during serialization. If you
>   are using the XmlSerializer class to
>   serialize an object, use the
>   XmlIgnoreAttribute class to get the
>   same functionality.

Mind you, I'm surprised your original code even compiles - when I try it, it says that `[NonSerialized]` can only be applied to fields...

Comment: The 'only applied to fields'...sorry, that was artifact of me sanitizing the code before posting. Edited the question to fix it.